# How to revert to old style outlining in VS2022 Preview?

Tags: visual-studio, ide, visual-studio-2022, visual-studio-preview

The latest Visual Studio 2022 Preview uses `˃/˅` to represent collapsed/expanded code. Is there a way to make VS use the old `+/-` symbols for that?

I got used to +/- and I hate visual changes that aren't optional, but I hope I'm wrong and there's an option for that and I just can't find it.

Comment: I think this is apart of them wanting most of their Microsoft apps to follow "the Microsoft Fluent design" as the "What's New?" page says. I don't see an option to change this back.  They don't explicitly call this out in the blog, but I think its part of the [UI refresh](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/visualstudio/introducing-visual-studio-17-9-preview-1-is-here/#ui-refresh-preview-and-tinted-themes) started in 17.9 preview 1.

Comment: @TimothyG. yeah, makes sense what you're saying. I hate it when they make visual changes without the option keep the previous style.

Comment: I bet if you search the [Visual Studio Feedback forum](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/VisualStudio) hard enough you'd probably find a complaint or two about not having a way to revert it (searching that site is terrible btw).  Then again its only in the preview build so far.  Give it some time until it makes the stable release and then you'll probably find some.